# How do I pre-fill a image field in a form with javascript

Tags: 8, javascript, media

I've got a form which I want to fill with javascript on a button click. This button click retrieves the data via a javascript call.

All regular fields are no issue, I just cant seem to be able to pre-fill the image (file) field. I've tried replacing the element with a rendered html block, which shows the image field but loses the functionality.

Any pointers/tips/solutions are very much appreciated. If you want to see some code, please let me know and I'll post it. I did not know what (if any) code to post, so to prevent a code-overflow I opted to post nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to programatically set the value for a file input field via JS? It's not possible because of browser security policies. If that's not it, yeah, if you could post the code that demos what you're trying to do that would be great

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I was trying to do. Guess I'll have to find a different way. Thanks for your quick response.